# UAT > How to check the ordering of data in a table using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I need to test that a resulting list is ordered date descending using selenium.

```
   this.Then(/^the list items should be ordered by date descending$/, (arg1): CucumberStepOutput =>  {
      actions
        return 'pending';
    });
```

I'm sure this is something that has been done many times by people in the selenium community - I am hoping someone will share best practice.

Comment: The order of the elements returned by Selenium is the same as the displayed order (if the position is not specified). So simply sort the column and then assert the text of each element against the expected list of dates.

Comment: That would work fine if I knew how to select the unique elements in order.  I suppose there is a way to do it with CSS and nth... but I couldn't get that to work with the selenium elements selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the answer or at least the solution I ended up with see the snippet below.

It's a bit ugly (comment with suggestions to clean up) but works!

```
this.Then(/^the list items should be in descending$/, (): CucumberStepOutput => {

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        let expectedValues = ['value1',
        'value2',
        'value3'
        ];
        client.elements('.element-class').then(elements => {
        let resultDates: Array<string> = [];
           elements.value.reduce<Promise<void>>((chain, nextElement) => {
               return chain.then(() => {
                   return client.elementIdText(nextElement.ELEMENT).then(text => {
                       resultVa.push(text.value);
                   });  
               });
           }, Promise.resolve()).then(()=>{
                 JSON.stringify(resultValues).should.equal(JSON.stringify(expectedValues));
                resolve();
           })

       });
    });
});
```